# Make svg with single line path fill up 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css, svg

How to make the svg with a single `<path>` tag making a horizontal line fill up the entire width of the parent container of the svg.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-goldstine-wh7td4?file=/src/index.tsx

```css
    .container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
      position: relative;
    }

    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    svg path {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
          <h4>
            Line should fill 100% width of the container of the svg. (the svg should be absolute
            positioned)
          </h4>
          <div class="container">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M 0,0 H 100%"
                // d="M 0, 5 L 100, 5"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
```

Comment: No chance you could embed your code in here in a snippet? YOu have reputation enough to know this at this point, right?

Comment: Why use a line when you can size a rectangle to 100% much more simply.?

Comment: Don't use % in the d attribute. Try using `d="M 0,0 H 1000"` instead, where 1000 is the width component of the viewBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it to 100% by modifying `d="M 0,0 H 100%"`.

For example, here I want to be 90% so I use: `d="M 0,0 H 900%"`

p.s: the percentage is relevant to with of the `viewbox` which is the third parameter: `viewBox="0 0 1000 1"`

```css
.container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
      position: relative;
    }

    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    svg path {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<h4>
            Line should fill 100% width of the container of the svg. (the svg should be absolute
            positioned)
          </h4>
          <div class="container">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M 0,0 H 900%"
                // d="M 0, 5 L 100, 5"
              />
            </svg>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented by **enxaneta**:
`<path>` elements **can't use percentage values**
unlike primitives like `<line>` , `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<ellipse>`.

See ["9.3.2. Specifying path data: the ‘d’ property"](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#TheDProperty)

So the obvious solution would be to use a `<line>` element instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

svg path {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" />
</svg>
</div>

<h3>No viewBox - fluid width</h3>
<div class="container" style="width:100%;  margin:1em 0; resize:both; overflow:auto; padding:1em; border:1px solid #ccc">
  <svg width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" />
</svg>
</div>


<h3>
  Don't preerve Aspect ratio - don't scale stroke-widths
</h3>
<div class="container" style="width:100%;  margin:1em 0; resize:both; overflow:auto; padding:1em; border:1px solid #ccc">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
              <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
                d="M 0,0 H 1000"
              />
            </svg>
</div>
```

You might also use `<line>` elements for fluid layout width - omitting the `<viewBox>` (See 2nd example)

If you really need to use `<path>` you might also apply [`preserveAspectRatio="none"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) and [`vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect) to get a similar behavior. (3rd example=